# Understanding commit in umysql

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

[umysql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/umysql/) is a fast MySQL Python driver with spotty documentation. I'm trying to understand how commit and auto-commit work. How can I enable or disable auto-commit? Is it on by default?

There's no `connection.commit()` function as in MySQLdb - If `autocommit` is off, how do I trigger a commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`umysqldb`](https://github.com/hongqn/umysqldb) wrapper around `umysql` and call [`connection.commit()`](https://github.com/hongqn/umysqldb/blob/develop/umysqldb/connections.py#L78) method.

Comment: Wow umysqldb looks awesome. Do you know if it impacts umysql's speed significantly?

Comment: @user939259 I doubt it has a serious impact but I haven't done performance tests personally. Hope it helps.

Comment: @user939259 I've also added a link to the `commit()` method. Essentially it just executes `COMMIT` query. So, if you'll notice an impact, just make `COMMIT` query directly in `umysql`.